# Getting 403 Forbidden in login-status-iframe.html in Keycloak React

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am trying to implement keycloak in a React application, but I am getting a 403 forbidden.
React runs on :3000
and Keycloak on port :8080
This is the Keycloak.ts

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
const keycloak = Keycloak({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: "keycloak-react-auth",
  clientId: "react",

});

export default keycloak;
```

index.ts

```
  import keycloak from './keycloak'
    import AppRouter from './routes/index'
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
    
    const eventLogger = (event: unknown, error: unknown) => {
      console.log('onKeycloakEvent', event, error)
    }
    
    const tokenLogger = (tokens: unknown) => {
      console.log('onKeycloakTokens', tokens)
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <ReactKeycloakProvider
          authClient={keycloak}
          onEvent={eventLogger}
          onTokens={tokenLogger}
        >
          <div style={{margin: '0px', padding: '0px', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
            <AppRouter />
          </div>
        </ReactKeycloakProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
```

This is the keycloak client config

[image]

Keycloak is running on latest version: `docker pull jboss/keycloak:latest`

On react :

1. "keycloak-js": "^20.0.3",
2. "@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",

Error code:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the answer was that the keycloak's client's web origin setting was incorrect. To check if this is the same problem for you login to the admin panel for keycloak, select the correct realm, select your client and change the web origin to just `+` and try to login from your application.

Also make sure you have a value in your `Valid redirect URIs`. To test on my local I just used `http://localhost:3000/*`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

To solve the issue, you should just remove the `/` from `http://localhost:3000/` in the `Web Origins` field.

So put in `Web Origins` : `http://localhost:3000` and it should work like my case

Comment: Correct Origin is critical for accessibility . Else the mentioned error comes.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put your Keycloak configuration file? It should be in public folder of your React app. Also, it is worth checking if you set it properly and logged in correctly, check your realm. You could take a look at this github issue report [on this address](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client/issues/468). You could check your logs on keycloak as well to check if it is configured well. I hope this helps you.
Also, on this [link](https://scalac.io/blog/user-authentication-keycloak-1/) you have a basic configuration with react, so be sure to read through it to check if you missed something in your config procces.

Comment: I tried but it is still the same output, I also changed the client config.

Comment: Your Realm is named React and in config you listed it as "keycloak-react-auth" if I am correct? Could you change it to "React" and tell me if it works?

Comment: My client is react and my realm is keycloak-react-auth in both configs.

Comment: Could you send ss of that response in headers, when you get that 403 response?

Comment: Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 09:40:24 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: I don't know if your server config or client config was wrong. You can try running this code (root index.js of React App) to ensure your server config working.
[link](https://jpst.it/35hzc)

Comment: Can you please give me a full code of how the index.ts should be done if you check I am also using ReactKeycloakProvider from "@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0", is that okay or should I change it

Comment: I am sorry I was away and I did not see your question, here is example with everything same as what you are using. So be free to check it, and in there you have index.ts file example. ([link](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/tree/master/examples/react-router))